# Fixing Gap in knowledge about C/C++ and register access

Tags: c++, c, arm, cpu-registers

Admittedly I am new to C++.  Unfortunately most of the code I have seen either uses the `asm` call or defines an `extern` function whose body is in an assembly file.

Which is why I was very exited to find the below code.  I have been studying the [codebase](https://github.com/rsta2/circle64) for 3 days now.

Syntactically I understand every line of the code below; except the one that counts because I don't get how it works!

1. types.h defines the `u32` and `uintptr` ( I have seen them)
2. ifdef __cplusplus is needed when C and C++ code are mixed.  Particularly because of the `extern C` which is C++ specific.  Can be omitted if gcc has the `-fno-exceptions` argument
3. `volatile` is used to prevent the compiler from doing any optimization because the address has to be bite perfect since it's writing/reading to/from registers.

All that said, I still have no idea how this code actually writes or reads from the register.

```
#include <circle/types.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

static inline u32 read32 (uintptr nAddress)
{
    return *(u32 volatile *) nAddress;
}

static inline void write32 (uintptr nAddress, u32 nValue)
{
    *(u32 volatile *) nAddress = nValue;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

What does `*(unsigned int *)` mean? How is this used to read and write to a register?  Wouldn't that `nAddress` have to be the physical address

Comment: `extern C` cannot be omitted. There is no mention of registers in the snippet.

Comment: nAddress would have to be a physical address or a virtual address mapped to the appropriate physical address. In this context, "register" is referring to a hardware register, not a cpu register.

Comment: This code does nothing to registers. It simply allows read or write of 32 bit int from any address in memory

Comment: `*(u32 volatile *)` is a dereference followed by a type cast to `u32 volatile *`

Comment: @pm100: It may read and write memory-mapped hardware registers.

Comment: Extern c has nothing to do with exceptions. It's to do with name mangling, google it

Comment: @PasserBy I hope you mean it's a type cast followed by a dereference...

Comment: What do you guys mean Hardware Register vs. CPU Register? I know what a CPU register is, what's a hardware register? Also this code run on the Pi3

Comment: This is a common trick in embedded / bare metal systems. There, the compiler has some guarantees about casting a number to a pointer, which allows you to use a physical address to get a pointer

Comment: @Justin Well... what I meant was, in the order by which its written, `*` is dereferencing and `(u32 volatile *)` is type casting.

Comment: @Justin Could you please summarize this all up in an answer? I think you get the code the most because you mentioned bare metal and that's precisely my goal right now.  I should probably change the tags?

Comment: @SamHammamy: On certain machines, probably mostly embedded devices these days, some addresses are not connected to memory but to registers in hardware devices. An example I'm familiar with is the Commodore 64, which had addresses in the range D000-DFFF used mostly for devices such as the SID (sound synthesizer chip), I/O device interfaces, VIA (video device), etc.

Comment: More info on [memory-mapped I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O).

Comment: @FredLarson Thanks! This makes sense.  I think it's writing to General Purpose IO (GPIO) on the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for "[memory mapped input-output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O)".

The most common way for CPU to talk to external hardware is through memory bus - the same bus that is used to access normal memory.

First, keep in mind that CPUs interaction with memory involves not just reads and writes, but also things like bus error handling (invalid access), arbitration (multiple devices accessing the same memory) and routing (CPU might want to access multiple memory devices). To handles this, a *bus protocol* is used.

To write or read external memory CPU has to initiate a *transaction*. The exact sequence of this is defined by used bus protocol, but it usually involves steps like:

- Sending transcation address, type, length etc.
- Receiving response - allowed or declined (bus error).
- Transmitting the actual data if transaction was allowed.

The device that initiates transcation is called *master* or *initiator*, while device that is responsible for handling the transaction is called *slave* or *target*.

Device that decides what slave handles the transaction is called *decoder* or *router*. So transaction will usually go from master to decoder and then to slave device.

Bus protocol essentialy provides a way to transfer data to or from a device. This device can be a memory device or anything else. In case of memory device, its controller handles transcations by writing or reading data to or from memory cell array.

If you are familiar with Object Oriented Programming, you can think of CPU being connected to external devices via *interface* which allows reading and writing at specified address. Implementation of this interface can do *anything*. And this how memory mapped I/O is done - CPU gets connected to a bunch of devices, each receiving transactions at specific address range. Write data to one address and this data will be received by memory device which will store it to memory cell array, write data to another address and it will be received by, lets say, SD controller and will be interpreted as "send SEND_STATUS command to SD card".

If you are also familiar with modern operating systems, you can think of "everything is a file" abstraction. Some files are just plain files e.g. they act as memory. Other files are different. Just like reading `/proc/cpuinfo` on Linux gives you information about your CPUs, reading at some address can provide you with information on what IRQs are currently pending or tell you how many incoming messages mailbox has at the moment.

Examples of bus protocols are [AXI](http://www.gstitt.ece.ufl.edu/courses/fall15/eel4720_5721/labs/refs/AXI4_specification.pdf) and [AHB](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs373/readings/ARM_IHI0033A_AMBA_AHB-Lite_SPEC.pdf). AHB is simpler, AXI is more complex and faster protocol. In case of Raspberry PI it is most likely AXI protocol that is used to connect CPU to hardware.

---

So regarding your question, those two functions are used to access registers of external devices via memory mapped I/O. Everything else you got right:

- `volatile` is used to prevent compiler from removing, reordering or in any way changing those memory accesses - without this hardware will not do what we want it to do.
- `u32` is used because many device will not even support anything but 32-bit accesses to keep hardware simple.

Comment: I think I finally get it!  The address in question here https://github.com/rsta2/circle64/blob/master/lib/bcmmailbox.cpp#L53  Is actually the address of the GPU's mailbox https://github.com/rsta2/circle64/blob/master/include/circle/bcm2835.h#L136.  

What I've learned so far is the GPU mailbox is a way for the CPU to send a message to the GPU so that the GPU can do things like turn on ACT LED, etc. My confusion was because the assembly version of this code actually puts that mailbox address into `r0` (general purpose ARM register).  Thanks again! Really made finally click!

Comment: @SamHammamy Yes, it is very common to have special device "mailbox" to transfer messages from one CPU to another. Unlike software-organazied queue in shared memory, mailbox can be more effecient and can provide additional features like notifications through IRQ about incoming messages.

Answer (score 2):

`(unsigned int *)` is a type casting to a pointer to `unsigned int`. The dereference operator `*` is used to access the memory location that this pointer points to.